# Regular expression for url rewriting to exclude strings beginning with a year

Tags: regex

I have a news page that detects tags based on the query string. So for instance, to filter out all news articles with a tag of 'Popular' I'd have:

```
<mydomain>/news/?tag=popular
```

I've set up a url rewrite in my config with the following:

```
<add name="newsrewrite"
     virtualUrl="^~/news/(.*)"
     rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
     destinationUrl="~/news?tag=$1"
     ignoreCase="true" />
```

This works fine. However I've noticed that I now can't access specific news article urls because it treats anything after /news/ as a querystring parameter.

ie. if I try to access /news/2015/news-article-1 then it won't work because the rewrite rule is essentially treating 2015/news-article-1 as the parameter.

Since I've structured my news articles under year folders, all news articles will always be accessed via /news/YYYY/article-title where YYYY is a 4-digit year.

Is there a regular expression I can use here that'll take anything after /news/ and use that as the querystring param EXCEPT those that begin with a 4-digit integer?

Thanks!

Comment: does your language support lookaheads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a regexp that will work like yours with the exception that it won't match /news/YYYY/.. have a look at this:

```
^\/news\/(?!\d{4})(.*)$
```

Note: it makes use of a negative lookahead (check if they are supported in your specific case). Also notice escape characters `\`.

Reading your problem I also though about a different approach: what about mapping through your rewriting only pages that match the actual tag structure? Something like this:

```
<add name="newsrewrite"
     virtualUrl="^~/news/?tag=(.*)"
     rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
     destinationUrl="~/news?tag=$1"
     ignoreCase="true" />
```

note that `$1` will contain only the tag (not `?tag=Popular`) like in your code. This should match only urls in the form `/news/?tag=SOMETHING` thus not matching your article pages.